# How can i extend the colors for coloring syntax in eclipse

Tags: html, syntax, highlighting

In eclipse menu I go to Window -> Preference. Then, In the Preference Dialog I go to Web -> HTML Files -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring. There I have some Elements. For these Elements I can define my favorite Colors and Styles. But I can define only ONE Color for ALL Tag Names.

Is there any way to define different colors for different Tags? For Example, separate colors for `<script>`, `<a>`, `<table>` and so on?

Answer (score 1):

Triptych is correct, there is no way to do that without editing Eclipse's core files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't do that, and I must say, the very idea of it offends my sensibilities.